# Datepicker onSelect not populating HiddenField

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Have searched SO for a solution but all examples don't seem to resolve my issue. The following is the recommended method and this works in a small project but fails with my example. Have also looked at Datepicker widget documentation and the onSelect is not very helpful:

```
$('.myTextBox').datepicker();
$('.myTextBox').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(){alert('hi')});
```

here is my code:

```
function noWeekEnds(date) {
  var kelly = ($(".myKelly").val()) - 1;
  var dow = date.getDay();
    if(dow==kelly) return [false,''];
    return [true,''];  
}

function unavailable(date) {
  var now = date;
  var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  var diff = now - start;
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  var nwe = noWeekEnds(date);
  var Ashift = (day%3===2) && nwe[0];  // A Shift
  var Bshift = (day%3===0) && nwe[0];  // B Shift
  var Cshift = (day%3===1) && nwe[0];  // C Shift

return [Cshift, "redback", "available"];
}

$(".myTextBox").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    onSelect: function (date) {
       alert("works");
    }

});
```

Comment: So when you select the date you need to populate a hidden input with that value...is that what you want?

Comment: yes - i tried to just capture the selected date to an alert first.

Comment: Where is `noWeekEnds` is defined? That is one error

Comment: sorry just left out that line, I will edit question...

Comment: Well it works for me now. http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/284/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myDate").datepicker();
$("#myDate").change(function(){
   $("#myHidden").val($(this).val());
    alert("Hidden value: " +  $("#myHidden").val());
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/4nd5hL9u/1/

#### Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/4nd5hL9u/2/

#### UPDATE:

#### Html:

```
<div class="divAndHidden">
 <input type="hidden" id="aspHidden" value="" />
</div>
```

#### Jquery:

```
$(".myTextBox").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: unavailable,
onSelect: function (date) {
   alert(this.value);
    $(".divAndHidden").find(":hidden").val(this.value); 
}
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/4nd5hL9u/4/

Comment: tried it with my functions and no go... I'm adding my function to the top `.datepicker`

Comment: yea, its just not working on mine? I'm using in a .net project with my text/hidden controls nested within other controls. I had to add a class tag to each of them to find them since ID's are dynamic.

Comment: It's working on the fiddle but it's not working on your project...weird issue...did you check for bugs in the javascript console?

Comment: not yet, have another issue as well - the `<asp:HiddenField>` will not allow parameter `class`

Comment: You can change your asp hidden fields for html hidden fields in your project, that should do the trick :)

Comment: actually fixed and resolved ID issue as well - found ID for TextBox control in firebug and used it (the class='xxx') did NOT work. - turned our my ID for the TextBox was: `#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE1TextBox`